# How to apply JOIN only if there are rows available

Tags: postgresql, join, query, exists

Given the following database:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Activity"
(
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    "designation" TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "UserType"
(
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    "designation" TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "User"
(
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    "name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "typeId" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "UserType"("id")
    -- ... and other fields
);

CREATE TABLE "Activity_UserType"
(
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    "activityId" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "Activity"("id"),
    "userTypeId" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "UserType"("id")
);
```

How to write the following query:

Select users that have access to a given activity. There is a a caveat, if no rows are present/linked in `Activity_UserType` to this activity then it means all UserTypes are allowed to access the activity.

I tried the following query:

```sql
SELECT "User"."id", "User"."name", "User"."typeId"
FROM "User"
JOIN "UserType" ON "User"."typeId" = "UserType"."id"
JOIN "Activity_UserType" ON "UserType"."id" = "Activity_UserType"."userTypeId"
WHERE "Activity_UserType"."activityId" = 1;
```

However, this only works if the table "Activity_UserType" is not empty. I tried to apply a ´LEFT JOIN` but also without success.

Here is a dbfiddle with comments (expected outputs):
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nGHMWKw3ytYrCXePkzvizq/6

Comment: Put what is needed to ask in your post, not just at a link.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 1):

This is one simple solution.

**Schema (PostgreSQL v15)**

```
CREATE TABLE "Activity"
(
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    "designation" TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "UserType"
(
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    "designation" TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "User"
(
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    "name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "typeId" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "UserType"("id")
    -- ... and other fields
);

CREATE TABLE "Activity_UserType"
(
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    "activityId" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "Activity"("id"),
    "userTypeId" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "UserType"("id")
);

INSERT INTO "UserType"(designation) VALUES ('UserType 1');
INSERT INTO "UserType"(designation) VALUES ('UserType 2');
INSERT INTO "UserType"(designation) VALUES ('UserType 3');

INSERT INTO "Activity"(designation) VALUES ('Activity All User Types');
INSERT INTO "Activity"(designation) VALUES ('Activity UserType 1');
INSERT INTO "Activity"(designation) VALUES ('Activity UserType 2');
INSERT INTO "Activity"(designation) VALUES ('Activity UserType 2 and 3');

INSERT INTO "Activity_UserType"("activityId", "userTypeId") VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO "Activity_UserType"("activityId", "userTypeId") VALUES (3, 2);

INSERT INTO "Activity_UserType"("activityId", "userTypeId") VALUES (4, 2);
INSERT INTO "Activity_UserType"("activityId", "userTypeId") VALUES (4, 3);

INSERT INTO "User"(name, "typeId") VALUES ('User - Type 1', 1);
INSERT INTO "User"(name, "typeId") VALUES ('User - Type 2', 2);
INSERT INTO "User"(name, "typeId") VALUES ('User - Type 3', 3);
```

---

**Query #1** -- Should return all users ('User - Type 1' and 'User - Type 2'  and 'User - Type 3')

```
SELECT "User"."id"
     , "User"."name"
     , "User"."typeId"
FROM "User"
    JOIN "UserType"
        ON "User"."typeId" = "UserType"."id"
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM "Activity_UserType"
    WHERE "Activity_UserType"."activityId" = 1
)
      OR EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM "Activity_UserType"
    WHERE "UserType"."id" = "Activity_UserType"."userTypeId"
          AND "Activity_UserType"."activityId" = 1
);
```

| id | name | typeId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User - Type 1 | 1 |
| 2 | User - Type 2 | 2 |
| 3 | User - Type 3 | 3 |

---

**Query #2** -- Should return users Type1 ('User - Type 1')

```
SELECT "User"."id"
     , "User"."name"
     , "User"."typeId"
FROM "User"
    JOIN "UserType"
        ON "User"."typeId" = "UserType"."id"
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM "Activity_UserType"
    WHERE "Activity_UserType"."activityId" = 2
)
      OR EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM "Activity_UserType"
    WHERE "UserType"."id" = "Activity_UserType"."userTypeId"
          AND "Activity_UserType"."activityId" = 2
);
```

| id | name | typeId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User - Type 1 | 1 |

---

**Query #3** -- Should return users Type2 ('User - Type 2')

```
SELECT "User"."id"
     , "User"."name"
     , "User"."typeId"
FROM "User"
    JOIN "UserType"
        ON "User"."typeId" = "UserType"."id"
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM "Activity_UserType"
    WHERE "Activity_UserType"."activityId" = 3
)
      OR EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM "Activity_UserType"
    WHERE "UserType"."id" = "Activity_UserType"."userTypeId"
          AND "Activity_UserType"."activityId" = 3
);
```

| id | name | typeId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | User - Type 2 | 2 |

---

**Query #4** -- Should return users Type2 and Type3 ('User - Type 2' and 'User - Type 3')

```
SELECT "User"."id"
     , "User"."name"
     , "User"."typeId"
FROM "User"
    JOIN "UserType"
        ON "User"."typeId" = "UserType"."id"
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM "Activity_UserType"
    WHERE "Activity_UserType"."activityId" = 4
)
      OR EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM "Activity_UserType"
    WHERE "UserType"."id" = "Activity_UserType"."userTypeId"
          AND "Activity_UserType"."activityId" = 4
);
```

| id | name | typeId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | User - Type 2 | 2 |
| 3 | User - Type 3 | 3 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m7GLMegie9VSRVwUUiC83K/0)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, return all users if no types are entitled explicitly. Check that in a CTE, and run a `UNION ALL` query depending on it:

```
WITH explicit AS (
   SELECT "userTypeId" AS "typeId"
   FROM   "Activity_UserType"
   WHERE  "activityId" = 1
   )
SELECT id, name, "typeId"
FROM   explicit
JOIN   "User" USING ("typeId")

UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, "typeId"
FROM   "User"
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (TABLE explicit);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xvxBUYjz)

I dropped the join to `"UserType"`. Referential integrity is enforced with FK constraints, and `"User"."typeId"` is `NOT NULL`, so the join would be noise in this query.

The query depends on *user types* being entitled, not *users*. There might be no users of an entitled type!

#### Relational design

Strictly speaking, you also need a `UNIQUE` constraint on table `"Activity_UserType"`, or there can be duplicates - which we would have to fold:

```
... CONSTRAINT activity_usertype_uni UNIQUE ("activityId", "userTypeId")
```

Or just make it the PK, like:

```
CREATE TABLE "Activity_UserType" (
  "activityId" int NOT NULL REFERENCES "Activity"(id)
, "userTypeId" int NOT NULL REFERENCES "UserType"(id)
, PRIMARY KEY ("activityId", "userTypeId")              -- !
);
```

##### Aside

Your life with Postgres will be easier with all legal, lower-case identifiers, that never require double-quotes. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860)